# Is there a straightforward way to determine the cardinality of a foreign key relationship using SMO?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, indexing, smo, cardinality

Using `SMO`, I'm trying to determine the **cardinality** of `ForeignKey` relationships between tables in a SQL Server database.  I could peruse each `ForeignKeyColumn` and look at each `Column` in the parent (and possibly also referenced) `Table`s, and look at the nullability of those columns as well as cross referencing with related `Index`es to determine **cardinality** (multiplicity on each end such as `0..1`, `1`, `*`) as illustrated by the following entity-relationship diagram:

[image]

But, there should be a more straightforward way to do this.  I don't see any relevant information in the `ForeignKey` `Properties` or `ExtendedProperties`.  The only item I could find in the MSDN Library was an [SfcCardinality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee226196.aspx) enumeration, which states "*Do not reference this member directly in your code. It supports the SQL Server infrastructure.*".

Is there a straight forward way to get **cardinality** information via SMO?

Comment: I don't mean to be dense, but could you clarify what you mean by cardinality?

Comment: Cardinality such as zero to one, one to one, one to many, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently determining the multiplicity of the foreign key relationship based on related indexes and columns.

Given 2 tables `A` and `B`, where `B` is the referenced table (principal) of a foreign key in `A`, I am able to determine 3 multiplicity cases using SMO:

#### One-to-one, where `B` must exist and `A` *may* exist:

```
A<-0..1----------1->B ()
```

This case is true if all of the columns of A in the foreign key relationship match a unique index within A.

#### Many-to-one, where `B` must exist if `A` is present, and `A` *may* exist:

```
A<-0..*----------1->B ()
```

This case is true if case 1 is not true and all of the columns of A in the foreign key relationship are not nullable.

#### Many-to-one, where `B` may exist if `A` is present, and `A` *may* exist:

```
A<-0..*----------0..1->B ()
```

This case is true if any of the columns of A in the foreign key relationship are nullable.

---

These 3 cases seem similar to what other tools such as Entity Framework can determine, so I'm not sure if it's easy to get additional multiplicity cases such as `A<-1----------1->B, A<-*----------1->B, or A<-n----------1->B`.  You probably would have to peruse constraints and/or triggers to glean additional information.

If there is a way to get more multiplicity cases, and/or a better way to get these cases, I'd love to know!